# Why is Kubernetes pod level "anti-affinity" is not being honored when creating pods in parallel?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-jobs

So I'm not sure if I'm using this feature incorrectly or it's a limitation of "anti-affinity" but I'm at a loss. I have a batch of jobs that I want to run with each one having their own node. Should be relatively simple, add the anti-affinity to only run the pod where the hostname + label does not exist. Despite this I still have multiple pods on the same node.

My best guess right now is that, because I create all the jobs at once with a `kubectl apply -f ./folder` command, the scheduler doesn't count pods on a node in the "container creating" state as a trigger for the anti-affinity rule and schedules another onto the node.

Each job needs a slightly different command line so I can't use just one job file with the parallel spec until 1.22 comes out with job indexing.

Below is the job yaml in case there's something I'm missing.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
 name: testjob-$SHARD
spec:
 backoffLimit: 1
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       run: testjob
   spec:
     affinity:
       podAntiAffinity:
         requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
         - labelSelector:
             matchExpressions:
             - key: run
               operator: In
               values:
               - testjob
           topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
     containers:
     - name: testjob
       imagePullPolicy: Always
       image: image
       resources:
         requests:
           memory: "3072Mi"
         limits:
           memory: "4Gi"
       command: ["./foo"]
       securityContext:
         privileged: true
     restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Answer (score 2):

So as a shot in the dark I upgraded my cluster from 1.20 to 1.21 and it magically fixed itself. So it's possible this was just a 1.20 problem. I have a issue on the kubernetes github to look into it but all I can say is that if you're on 1.20 and having trouble with pod level anti-affinity maybe try upgrading.

Comment: Can you share the URL of your Github issue? I tried looking for it but did not see it. We are on 1.20 as well and would love if there was some fix in 1.21 to convince us to upgrade.

Comment: NVM I found it https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/104213 I think!